# How to match code comment with regex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

given below sample code

```
      get => "hello#index" # comments
```

How to macth '# comments' ?

There is Ruby regular expression editor http://rubular.com/ for test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the unrealistic case in which you want to match any text at all after the **last** hash you can use

```
/#[^#]*$/
```

But there is no guarantee the last hash actually begins a comment.  If a line had a hash inside a string literal or was itself used as a delimiter in a `%w`, for example

```
%w# abc def #
```

or was used in something like this

```
dog = "spike"
%w{#dog rat}
```

then you will have a difficult time trying to come up with a regex.  I would go with a ruby parser.

Comment: It sounds like I should use ruby synax parser to do this thing. I am writing a ruby obfuscator.

Comment: Indeed. I do think a syntax parser is the only reliable way to remove comments given that the hash symbol can appear in many different contexts including in `#{}` forms and string literals and `%w{}` forms for which I am not sure a regex is powerful enough in general (though it might be with some effort).  The fact that you are writing an obfuscator, though, means you definitely want the full power of a parser so you can perform a wide variety of transforms.  These transforms **should** be done on the abstract syntax tree rather than on the (linear) Ruby text.

Answer (score -1):

`/# comments/` would work fine